# Difference between WebComponent and lit-html

Tags: polymer, web-component, lit-html

Hi am started to looking into the Polymer3 and came to know about the lit-html and i couldn't understand what are the major differences between lit-html and web components? expect the lit-html's html tag. could some one explain more in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Those two are not really comparable technologies. Anyway if you want to learn more about them I suggest looking for those pages.

lit-html lets you write HTML templates in JavaScript using template literals with embedded JavaScript expressions. lit-html identifies the static and dynamic parts of your templates so it can efficiently update just the changed portions. [Docs](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide)

Web Components is a suite of different technologies allowing you to create reusable custom elements — with their functionality encapsulated away from the rest of your code — and utilize them in your web apps. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

Comment: I slightly disagree. They are totally comparable technologies. Lit-Element is a wrapper **around** native W3C standard Custom Elements (aka Web Components) Lit is the can of tomato soup, custom elements are the tomatoes. Your choice what cook you want to be.

Comment: Question is not compare lit-element and web-component, they are asking lit-html comparing with web components?

Comment: Yes, Lit-HTML is the can, Lit-Element are the diced tomatoes. If I am right (but don't can me on this) Lit-HTML can be used without Lit-Element, but Lit-Element uses Lit-HTML, although I have only seen the combination in the wild. The essence is Custom Elements/Web Components is a W3C standard/foundation, available in all modern Browsers. LIT is tooling built on top of standards (Lit-HTML on Template Literals, Lit-Element on Custom Elements), There are many competitors to LIT: Hybrids, StencilJS, hyperHTML etc. Just like jQuery had 20 competitors 10 years ago.